# Uploading animated GIFS

Tags: discussion, images

How do you upload animated GIFs to a post? I was trying to, but it told me 

`"Failed to upload image; the format is not supported"`

So, are they not supported, or am I just exporting the GIF wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It definitely works; see here:

[Inbox message count animation too slow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104046/inbox-message-count-animation-too-slow/104176#104176)

So presumably the format of your image is somehow incorrect.

Comment: You can grab another one that works in the site from here http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17759/what-tiny-thing-in-lion-makes-you-smile-or-has-caught-you-off-guard/18694#18694 and perhaps compare these to your gif that's not yet dancing about (to the dismay of many that wish these die with fire) ...